# google maps change v2 into version v3 problems

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some problems with upgrading google maps v2 in v3.

Follow code is v2:

```
function routing(target, width, lenght, name, zip, city, street) {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        if (counter > 0) {directions.clear()};
        counter++;
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
        directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);

        var startpoint = name+', '+zip+' '+city+', '+street

        if (target == 'messe') {
        directions.load("from: "+startpoint+"@"+width+","+lenght+" to: Messe, 50679 #T_koeln#, Deutz-Mülheimer Straße 40@50.9473327,6.98312820000001");
        };

        if (target == 'airport') {
        directions.load("from: "+startpoint+"@"+width+","+lenght+" to: Flughafen Koeln, 50679 #T_koeln#, Kennedystraße@50.8782914,7.122399800000039");
        };
    }
}
```

here is the v3 code:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
function routing(target, width, lenght, name, zip, city, street) {
    if (counter > 0) {directionsDisplay.setMap(null)};
    counter++;

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: #zoomfaktor_detail#,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(width, length), 
        overviewMapControl: true,
        overviewMapControlOptions:{opened:true},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("route"));
    var startpoint = name+', '+zip+' '+city+', '+street

    if (target == 'messe') {
        end = 'Messe, 50679 #T_koeln#, Deutz-Mülheimer Straße 40@50.9473327,6.98312820000001';
        start = startpoint+"@"+width+","+lenght;
        request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
    }
    if (target == 'airport') {
        end = 'Flughafen Koeln, 50679 #T_koeln#, Kennedystraße@50.8782914,7.122399800000039';
        start = startpoint+"@"+width+","+lenght;
        request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
    }
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Why does it not function? Has someone an idea?

Comment: well for starters you've spelled this argument incorrectly, which will cause an error: `lenght`.  You refer to it using that spelling most places, apart from here, where it won't work: `center: new google.maps.LatLng(width, length), `

Comment: Also are you getting any Javascript errors?

Comment: no, its not the problem. I changed the variable names because its written in german in may originally code

Comment: no Iam not. the map does not show the route

Comment: What is the value of "status"? `if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);} else alert("Directions failed, status="+status");`

Comment: Directions failed, status=NOT_FOUND

Comment: what's this meant to be?  `zoom: #zoomfaktor_detail#,`

Comment: You should run all your javascript through JSLint or JSHint to identify all the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: zoom: #zoomfaktor_detail# is 17

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because the route can't be found and the directions service is returning an error which is (or was) being silently ignored.

I suspect the problem is the "@" in your start and end addresses.  Remove them (and the text after them), give the directions service valid addresses (or give it the coordinates as a google.maps.LatLng object).

Comment: yes, if I give the coordinates as a google.maps.LatLng its working. my problem is, to show the name of the location first. for example (look at the picture) http://i40.tinypic.com/2eal5qs.jpg  and than the street, zip, city and country. But now its look like so http://i41.tinypic.com/22mg05.jpg how can I do that?